# Фиксированная панель. Плавность

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Имеется панель, которая находится **под** шапкой. Сделал ей фиксацию, и она действительно зафиксировалась. Но она по середине при прокрутке страницы! Как бы сделать чтобы она фиксировалась только когда начинала уходить из виду? И становилась обратно при подъеме страницы вверх? Желательно на `html`, если возможно. Я просто его понимаю больше, чем `jQuery` или `js`.

Как я делал фиксацию:

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      #container {
         height: 70px;
         position: relative;
         z-index : 2000;
      }
      #fixed-div {

         position: fixed;

         width: 1223px;
         top: 120px;
         left: 17px;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="fixed-div">

**Тут код самой панели.**

</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий пример на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/WkHEL/)**

**html**

```
<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="fixed-div" class="no-scroll">

      **Тут код самой панели.**

      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $menu = $("#fixed-div");
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 70 && $menu.hasClass("no-scroll")) {
            $menu.removeClass("no-scroll").addClass("scroll");
        } else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 70 && $menu.hasClass("scroll")) {
            $menu.removeClass("scroll").addClass("no-scroll");
        }
    });
});
```

**css**

```
#container {
    height: 70px;        
    z-index : 2000;
}
#fixed-div {
    width: 1223px;    
}
.no-scroll{
    position: relative;
}
.scroll {        
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

/* для демонстрации */
#fixed-div {    
    border: 1px black solid;
}
.scroll {
    background-color: rgba(108, 105, 101, 0.7) !important;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```